# JS won't execute in page (works in jsfiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would first like to say that I am very new to JavaScript and Jquery, so this is hopefully a simple one,

I have some JS code to arrange the order of a few div tags which works in JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/databass/Yh2L3/)

However when I try and put that into a webpage nothing happens

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

  <script>
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
var divElements = $('#tours div'),
    sortType = $(this).data('sort');

divElements.sort(function (a, b) {

    a = $(a).data(sortType);
    b = $(b).data(sortType);

// compare
    if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else if (a < b) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

$('#tours').empty();
$.each(divElements, function (i, divElement) {
    $('#tours').append(divElement.outerHTML);
});

});

  </script>

</head>

<body>

<button data-sort='price'>Sort By Price</button>
<button data-sort='duration'>Sort By Duration</button>
<button data-sort='name'>Sort By Name</button>
<section id="tours">
<div class="result" data-price="749" data-duration="8" data-name="Basecamp">Info about tour 1 goes here</div>
<div class="result" data-price="2099" data-duration="19" data-name="Cycle Adventure">Info about tour 2 goes here</div>
<div class="result" data-price="1099" data-duration="25" data-name="Family Adventure">Info about tour 3 goes here</div>
<div class="result" data-price="3014" data-duration="18" data-name="Luxury Basecamp">Info about tour 4 goes here</div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `javascript` code you have executes before the elements being added to `DOM`. You need to put the javascript code just before the `body` ending tag or in [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code, [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: And, it worked in the jsFiddle because the jsFiddle was set to run the javascript in an `onLoad` handler.  Set it to "in <head>" and the jsFiddle has the same problem.